# Oracle INSERT INTO using SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to duplicate some columns rows in Oracle.

I have a table `customer_address` and column `address_type` where 1 is delivery address, 2 is delivery address etc.

I have this columns that I need to duplicate:

```
customer_no
customer_name
customer_email
```

So for example at the moment

```
 CUSTOMER_NO ADDRESS_TYPE CUSTOMER_NAME CUSTOMER_EMAIL
 ----------- ------------ ------------- --------------
 40          1            Some Customer email@somecustomer.com
```

but what I want is

```
 CUSTOMER_NO ADDRESS_TYPE CUSTOMER_NAME CUSTOMER_EMAIL
 ----------- ------------ ------------- --------------
 40          1            Some Customer email@somecustomer.com
 40          2            Some Customer email@somecustomer.com
```

Is it possible to do it?

### Update

Thanks for the answer @a_horse_with_no_name, but when I query the table the results seem odd, I get the column names twice, is this correct or did I miss something that has caused this?

For example

```
select customer_no, address_type, customer_name, customer_email
from   customer_address
where  customer_no = 40;
```

shows

```
 CUSTOMER_NO ADDRESS_TYPE CUSTOMER_NAME CUSTOMER_EMAIL
 ----------- ------------ ------------- --------------
 40          1            Some Customer email@somecustomer.com
 CUSTOMER_NO ADDRESS_TYPE CUSTOMER_NAME CUSTOMER_EMAIL
 ----------- ------------ ------------- --------------
 40          2            Some Customer email@somecustomer.com
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
insert into customer_address (customer_no, address_type, customer_name, customer_email)
select customer_no,
       2,
       customer_name, 
       customer_email
from customer_address
where customer_id = 40
  and address_type = 1;
commit;
```

For a complete description of the `INSERT` syntax, please see the manual:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9014.htm#SQLRF01604

Comment: That is the output generated by SQL*Plus. Use a different tool or configure SQL*Plus differently (but that is a different question, don't change this one)

Comment: I just done the same query at another site and I don't get the double headers. Is that just because the Oracle or SQL*Plus version is different?